# How can I read parameter attribute value in web api action filter

Tags: c#, api, actionfilterattribute

I've got an API method where the Id parameter is annotated with CacheType attribute

```
public Object Get([CacheType(CacheTypes.Venue)]int Id)
{
            ....
}
```

Can I read the value of the parameter attribute inside of ActionFilterAttribute

```
public class CacheOutputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
        //read CacheType value
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tied anything yourself or are you just copying code from the net and asking us to do the work for you?

Comment: It's possible with help of Reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the collection of parameters of currently executed method, you invoke

```
actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()
```

You can that iterate through the collection of `HttpParameterDescriptor` and find the parameter you need. You can do it by name, index or whatever means you find appropriate.

Then, you can use method `GetCustomAttributes<TClass>()` defined in object of type `HttpParameterDescriptor` to check if the parameter is marked with attribute of type `TClass`. If you need an instance of the attribute to check the value, simply get it from the resulting collection of attributes (if found).

Answer (score 3):

To get the parameter value

```
actionContext.ActionArguments["id"]
```

To do something with the parameters that have `CacheOutput` attribute

```
actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().ToList().ForEach(p =>
{
    var cacheOutput = p.GetCustomAttributes<CacheOutputAttribute>();
    if (cacheOutput.Any())
    {
        // do something 
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't the ActionArguments contain only pairs of name/value and not metadata of the method argument?